# How to set back colors to dynamic columns in c1 flex grid

Tags: vb.net, c1flexgrid

I am generating a report in vb.net using **c1flexgrid** in which some columns are dynamic. I need to set various back colors for these columns.

How to achieve this?

Comment: did you make any attempt? share your code and info about the issues.

Comment: columns are generated dynamically..  i dont know how to set styles for these colunms.. i know how to set styles if i know the rows exactly.  but in this situation say 10 coumns are there . how to set different colors for these columns?

Comment: Try using OwnerDrawCell for C1FlexGrid